# mongoDB Collection LRU Policy +java

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongoDB. I am working on building an application which requires implementing LRU policy on the collection. In the mongoDB site i see capped collections support FIFO. Is there any other collection which support LRU. Throught the documentation i see only capped collections in the site. Are there any other collections in mongoDb.

Are collections by default capped in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB capped collections are the only kilobyte size-limited collections supported by the database. There is no built-in support for LRU or FIFO based on limiting to a particular number of documents.

Collections are not capped by default in MongoDB - a capped collection is a special case.

Comment: So Is it right if a say like if i want to limit the size of a collection in a monoDb i can only do it if it is a capped collection

Comment: The capped collection will automatically remain at the limited size, in bytes. That is the only way of limiting the size of a collection at the database level. If on the other hand you want to limit a collection by the number of documents or the age of the documents, you will need to code that in your client application. There is no native support for either limit within MongoDB itself.

Comment: What is the default type of a collection. How can i see the type of a collection created. When i look using stats cmd i dont find it.

Comment: Collections are not capped by default. For info on how to know if a collection is capped, see [my answer and comment to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719412/how-can-you-tell-if-a-collection-is-capped/4720366#4720366).

Comment: You actually can use capped collections to limit the number of documents in a collection. Check out the max option for a capped collection. You must also specify a size in bytes. Documents are removed when either of the two limits is reached. So, you need to set the size high enough based on how big you expect the documents to be. This is useful for things like keeping the last n events of a certain type.